Why am I getting “Can't have overlapping partitions” errors with Proxmox on Ubuntu?
I have increased the disk size in the Proxmox settings and am now attempting to resize the disk size of the Ubuntu client. Unfortunately, when I try to execute the command resizepart 5 100%, I encounter an error:

Can't have overlapping partitions

What causes this error to occur, and how do I solve it?
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 2.5 TiB, 2684354560000 bytes, 5242880000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdc1d790f

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048     999423     997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 3565156351 3564154882  1.7T  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 3565156351 3564154880  1.7T 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/mail--vg-root: 1.7 TiB, 1798974734336 bytes, 3513622528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/mail--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0  2.5T  0 disk
├─sda1                8:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                8:2    0    1K  0 part
└─sda5                8:5    0  1.7T  0 part
  ├─mail--vg-root   253:0    0  1.7T  0 lvm  /
  └─mail--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]

dfdisk
                                                     Disk: /dev/sda
                                 Size: 2.5 TiB, 2684354560000 bytes, 5242880000 sectors
                                           Label: dos, identifier: 0xdc1d790f

    Device            Boot                  Start              End          Sectors        Size      Id Type
>>  /dev/sda1         *                      2048           999423           997376        487M      83 Linux
    /dev/sda2                             1001470       3565156351       3564154882        1.7T       5 Extended
    └─/dev/sda5                           1001472       3565156351       3564154880        1.7T      8e Linux LVM
    Free space                         3565156352       5242879999       1677723648        800G

parted
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2684GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   primary   ext2         boot
 2      513MB   1825GB  1825GB  extended
 5      513MB   1825GB  1825GB  logical                lvm


sda2 and sda5 overlap. I also suspect the disk is MBR not GPT.

Do you have any advice on how to correct the overlap between sda2 and sda5?

You have LVM therefore you need to use LVM tools.
